# field injection without constructor or setters

Tags: java, spring

I have a jar java class that use spring field injection, with an empty constructor

```
public JarClass {

@Autowired
private JarField jarfield;

public JarClass() {}

}
```

I would like to import this bean into another project with the field jarField initialized

so far, I created a class in another project like this

```
@Configuration
public class Config {


@Bean
public JarField jarField() {
return new JarField();
}

@Bean
public JarClass jarClass() {
return new JarClass();
}

}
```

if I had a constructor to inject dependencies inside JarClass, like

```
public JarClass {

private JarField jarfield;

this.jarField = jarField;

public JarClass(JarField jarfield) {

}
```

I could easily set the field like this :

```
@Configuration
public class Config {


@Bean
public JarField jarField() {
return new JarField();
}

@Bean
public JarClass jarClass(@Bean JarField jarField) {
return new JarClass(jarField);
}

}
```

}

But I have neither a constructor or a setter to do so.

Any Idea to make my JarField not null without changing the remote class JarClass ?

}

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize bean after another bean using **dependsOn** annotation.

Also, you need to initialize the bean manually, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;    

  @Bean
  public JarField jarField() {
    return new JarField();
  }

  @Bean
  @DependsOn({"jarField"})
  public JarClass jarClass() {
    JarClass jarClass = new JarClass();
    AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    factory.autowireBean( jarClass );
    return jarClass;
  }

}
```

**autowireBean** method will process **@Autowired** fields and methods. If you also need to invoke post processing (**@PostConstruct** and any defined **BeanPostProcessors**), then also use:

```
factory.initializeBean( jarClass, "jarClass" );
```

Answer (score -1):

Change:

```
public JarClass {

private JarField jarfield;

this.jarField = jarField;

public JarClass(JarField jarfield) {

}
```

Into this:

```
public JarClass {
   private final JarField jarfield;
   
   @Autowired
   public JarClass(JarField jarfield) {
       this.jarField = jarField;
   }
}
```

Comment: No modifications of jarClass is possible

Comment: Well, you can create new class that extend your JarClass and fix the null part.